# Finding cosine Similarity between 2 csr_matrices

Tags: scipy, nlp, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I have 2 `csr_matrix`. I want to compute cosine similarity between each vector of first matrix with each vector of 2nd matrix. For this purpose I am firstly building full vector **including zeros** from 1st matrix and then finding dot product product with every **full vector** of 2nd matrix. Is there any other way of doing this ? If the question is not clear , please let me know, however, I tried my best to explain.

Comment: Doesn't [scikit's cosine distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances.html) take sparse matrices? Just use that.

Comment: I dont want to use scikit library. It is requirement to use minimum dependencies on libraries.

Comment: If this isn't a homework assignment, scikit is absolutely stable enough to use as a dependency and you should use that. If this is a homework assignment, do your own homework.